# Difference between wkt and str

Tags: python, string, shapely, wkt

I have a shapely Polygon. What is the difference between converting it to wkt and converting it to string:

```
import shapely.wkt

P = shapely.wkt.loads('POLYGON ((8.0 3.0, 8.3 3.3, 8.3 3.0, 8.0
3.0))')

print(P.wkt)

print(str(P))
```

Is the result always the same? And can these two be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same. Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/blob/28b748f35ec0483da7bd8fc64b65ee5eee0aff1d/shapely/geometry/base.py#L245) `BaseGeometry.__str__()` method returns `self.wkt`.

So with `P.wkt` or `str(P)` you get the same [Well Known Text (WKT) representation](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#well-known-formats).